# Unable to create parquet column scanner

Tags: amazon-redshift, parquet, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am trying to load the parquet data from S3 into redshift and I am running following command:

```
COPY sample_table
FROM 's3://sample_s3/parquet_data/'
IAM_ROLE '<arn>'
FORMAT AS PARQUET;
```

but as soon as I run this command, I am getting this error:

```
DETAIL:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Spectrum Scan Error
  code:      15001
  context:   Unable to create parquet column scanner
  query:     21099
  location:  dory_util.cpp:1141
  process:   worker_thread [pid=6570]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

and FYI, this is happening only for few tables and not for all the tables. I have 7 tables out of which I am getting this for only 2 tables and not able to figure out the issue.
Any help or anyone have ever received this issue?

Comment: hi @arglee did you find the reason or solution to this error?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue and it turned out to be how decimal values were encoded. According to the parquet-cli, a decimal value was being encoded as `binary (STRING)`. What Redshift wanted was `fixed_len_byte_array(5) (DECIMAL(10,4))`.

To fix the issue, I converted the string values to decimal with the following Python code (which uses Pandas and PyArrow):

```
import pyarrow as pa
new_values = pa.chunked_array(pa.Array.from_pandas(table.column('score').to_pandas().astype(float)).cast(pa.decimal128(10, 4)))
table = table.set_column(position, 'score', new_values)
```

I would also like to point out that the `pa.chunked_array` is necessary. Using only a PyArrow Array is not enough to get the proper type.

Just in case it may help with similar problems: I found this by first exporting some data from Redshift with the `UNLOAD` command and working backwards from there.